# Open sessionURL for Autobahn websocket in browser

Tags: javascript, apache, websocket, autobahn, paraview

I have a Pyramid web application on which I would like to embed an iFrame displaying an instance of ParaViewWeb's visualizer so users can display VTU files remotely.

I have successfully done so while running the application on my own workstation by calling a subprocess from Python that executes ParaViewWeb's Quick Start method and returns the URL to JavaScript for iFrame generation.

http://www.paraview.org/ParaView3/Doc/Nightly/www/js-doc/index.html#!/guide/quick_start

However, in order to accommodate multiple users, ParaViewWeb's documentation indicates that

> the server must provide a single entry point to establish a connection, as well as a mechanism to start a new visualization session on demand

for which it suggests using Apache as the front-end application and a python launcher to start the process for each session.

Conveniently, I have a "freshly installed Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS" so I used the following guide to configure both the launcher and Apache:

http://www.paraview.org/ParaView3/Doc/Nightly/www/js-doc/index.html#!/guide/ubuntu_14_04

Ok so I'm pretty sure I am missing something major here, but once the launcher is started with /data/pvw/bin/start.sh... how do I then submit the request with information regarding what app to use (visualizer) and what data directory to load???

**Update**

I am able to launch a session such that a sessionURL with a unique ID is returned by first running

```
/data/pvw/bin$ ./start.sh
```

and then entering the following commands in the python interpreter

```
>>> import requests
>>> import json
>>> data = {"sessionManagerURL": "http://localhost:8080/paraview", "application": "visualizer"}
>>> data = json.dumps(data)
>>> r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/paraview",data=data)
>>> r.json()['sessionURL']
    u'ws://localhost/proxy?sessionId=e2970d68-42c8-11e5-a755-3c970e8061f9'
```

So now I have a websocket which should contain an instance of ParaViewWeb that I would like to access from the browser... typing the sessionURL as is into the browser does nothing and replacing 'ws' with 'http' opens a page with the following text:

> AutobahnPython 0.6.0
>
> I am not Web server, but a WebSocket endpoint. You can talk to me using the WebSocket protocol.
>
> For more information, please visit my homepage.

I am new to both apache and websockets so I am reading up on the protocol on the homepage, but if someone has a quick answer about how to utilize this websocket to display ParaViewWeb to the user I would be very appreciative!!

**Note:** Command line argument -dr is unknown so omit it from all of the command line arguments given in the guide's launcher.json

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not familiar with ParaViewWeb, but this is what I have done with Pyramid and IPython Notebook for on-demand process launching: https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/pyramid_notebook